# if文とfor文を組み合わせた際の挙動

Tags: python, python3

pythonでfor文を回し、bs4でとってきたリンクを出力し、リンクがない場合はFalseを出力するプログラムを作っています。
下記のコードでは、リンクがある、ないに関わらずFalseが出てしまいます。
解決策があればご教示お願いいたします。

```
for a_tag in soup.find_all('a'):
            link_pdf = (urljoin(cur_url, a_tag.get('href')))
            #if '/ResultDataSetPDF/' not in link_pdf:
            #link_PDFから文末がpdfと文中にPDFが入っているものを抽出

            if (not link_pdf.lower().endswith('.pdf')) and ('/ResultDataSetPDF/' not in link_pdf):
                continue
            if ('searchhelp' not in link_pdf):
                print(link_pdf)
            if (''  in link_pdf):
                print('False')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> リンクがない場合はFalseを出力するプログラムを作っています。

上記を、以下のように解釈して良いのであれば、

> bs4でとってきたリンクの集まりに1つもPDFのリンクがない場合に`Flase`を出力する

フラッグを使った以下の方式はいかがでしょうか。

```
# PDFリンク有りフラッグ(リンクの集まり内に1つでもPDFリンクがあるか)
has_pdf_link = False

# リンクの集まりを1つずつ調査
for a_tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    link_pdf = (urljoin(cur_url, a_tag.get('href')))
    #link_PDFから文末がpdfと文中にPDFが入っているものを抽出
    if (not link_pdf.lower().endswith('.pdf')) and ('/ResultDataSetPDF/' not in link_pdf):
        continue
    # PDFのリンクの場合、PDFリンク有りフラッグをTrueに
    if ('searchhelp' not in link_pdf):
        has_pdf_link = True
        print(link_pdf)

# リンクの集まりに1つもPDFのリンクがない場合に`Flase`を出力する
if not has_pdf_link:
    print('False')
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。返信が遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。正常に作動し、PDFがあるものとないものの区別することができました。